# Add/reload mapview annotations without blocking main thread

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, annotations, mkmapview, reload

I can perfectly load my map view with annotations the first time. However, if i try to reload the map on a button click (after its already loaded), the user has to wait till the process completes.
This problem has arisen because on reload, the new annotations dont appear until the mapview is moved significantly, that's when the *viewForAnnotation* fires. I've seen two other questions similar to mine with solutions involving '**performSelectorInBackground**' & '**performSelectorOnMainThread**'. The former didnt work for me :( & the latter i dont want to do (though it's the only option that works) as i want the user to be able to interact with the map while the annotations load without blocking the main thread. I'm aware that such animations are best done on the main thread, so the question(s) 1. Is there no other way to do it than having the user wait till the map reloads? 2. Suggestions on the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dispatch queue block to achieve this
here is the syntax
You can create your on private queue like this

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.AppTask",NULL);
dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(queue, 
    ^{
        //do the fetching of data here(Don't do any UI Updates)
        dispatch_async(main, 
        ^{
           // Do the UI Update here.
         });

     });
```

Apple has referred to this as recursive decomposition.
In this bit of code the computation is offloaded onto a background thread with `dispatch_async()` and
then `dispatch_async()` back into the main queue which will schedule our block to run with the updated data that we computed in the background thread.

Comment: I was a little short on time to try this so i ended up fetching the data in a background thread and displaying the annotations on the main thread. Probably similar approach to a dispatch queue. Hence marking it as the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of adding/removing 100's of Annotations at the same time. As you said, all UI operations have to be in the main thread. The solution to this is just to limit the number of pins on the screen at one time, either through clustering or some other way (showing top 50 nearest to the center of the screen).

Comment: Also don't see the need for a separate queue, just use dispatch_get_global_queue